# Output unique XSLT attribute values when using a key nested within another key

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, muenchian-grouping

I have been working on a web page constructed through a combination of *XSLT 1.0* and *XML* and come across a problem where I have been struggling to export unique attribute values while using a [XSL Key](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_key.asp) (`<xsl:keyname="name" match="pattern" use="expression"/>`) nested within another XSL Key.

Due to the sensitivity of my XML data, I have reconstructed my problem exactly using the 'classic W3C Schools example' of a bookstore.

**The Code:**

*XSL:*

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="prom-by-id" match="bookstore/promotion" use="promotionID"/>
<xsl:key name="location-by-id" match="bookstore/locations" use="locationID"/>

<xsl:template match="bookstore">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="book"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="book">
  <xsl:copy>
     <p><strong><xsl:value-of select="title"/></strong></p>
          <xsl:for-each select="key('prom-by-id', occurrences/promotions/promotionNum)">
            <xsl:for-each select="key('location-by-id', promotionLocation)">
              <p><xsl:value-of select="location"/></p>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:for-each>
     <br/><br/>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

*XML:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="books.xsl" ?>
<bookstore>
  <book>
    <title>Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone</title>
    <author>J K. Rowling</author>
    <year>1997</year>
    <price>3.99</price>
    <publisher>Bloomsbury (UK)</publisher>
    <synopsis>
         Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone is the first novel in the Harry Potter series and J. K. Rowling's debut novel.

         The plot follows Harry Potter, a young wizard who discovers his magical heritage as he makes close friends and a few enemies in his first year at the Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and Wizardry.

         With the help of his friends, Harry faces an attempted comeback by the dark wizard Lord Voldemort, who killed Harry's parents, but failed to kill Harry when he was just a year old.
   </synopsis>
   <occurrences>
    <promotions>
      <promotionCode>1</promotionCode>
      <promotionNum>1</promotionNum>
      <promotionNum>2</promotionNum>
      <promotionNum>3</promotionNum>
      <promotionNum>4</promotionNum>
   </promotions>
   </occurrences>
 </book>
 <book>
    <title>The Girl with the Dragon Tattoo</title>
    <author>Stieg Larsson</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>5.99</price>
    <publisher>Norstedts Förlag (SWE)</publisher>
    <synopsis>
         In Stockholm, Sweden, journalist Mikael Blomkvist, co-owner of Millennium magazine, has lost a libel case brought against him by businessman Hans-Erik Wennerström. Lisbeth Salander, a brilliant but troubled investigator and hacker, compiles an extensive background check on Blomkvist for business magnate Henrik Vanger, who has a special task for him. 

         In exchange for the promise of damning information about Wennerström, Blomkvist agrees to investigate the disappearance and assumed murder of Henrik's grandniece, Harriet, 40 years ago. 

         After moving to the Vanger family's compound, Blomkvist uncovers a notebook containing a list of names and numbers that no one has been able to decipher.
    </synopsis>
    <occurrences>
      <promotions>
         <promotionCode>3</promotionCode>
        <promotionNum>5</promotionNum>
        <promotionNum>6</promotionNum>
        <promotionNum>3</promotionNum>
        <promotionNum>2</promotionNum>
      </promotions>
    </occurrences>
  </book>
   <book>
    <title>Grandpa's Great Escape</title>
    <author>David Walliams</author>
    <year>2015</year>
    <price>5.00</price>
    <publisher>Harper Collins Children's Books</publisher>
    <synopsis>
         An exquisite portrait of the bond between a small boy and his beloved Grandpa – this book takes readers on an incredible journey with Spitfires over London and Great Escapes through the city in a high octane adventure full of comedy and heart. Illustrated by the award-winning Tony Ross.
    </synopsis>
    <occurrences>
    <promotions>
      <promotionCode>4</promotionCode>
      <promotionNum>1</promotionNum>
      <promotionNum>2</promotionNum>
      <promotionNum>4</promotionNum>
   </promotions>
 </occurrences>
  </book>
<book>
    <title>A Brief History of Seven Killings</title>
    <author>Marlon James</author>
    <year>2015</year>
    <price>6.29</price>
    <publisher>Oneworld Publications</publisher>
    <synopsis>
         From the acclaimed author of The Book of Night Women comes a dazzling display of masterful storytelling exploring this near-mythic event. Spanning three decades and crossing continents, A Brief History of Seven Killings chronicles the lives of a host of unforgettable characters – slum kids, one-night stands, drug lords, girlfriends, gunmen, journalists, and even the CIA. 

         Gripping and inventive, ambitious and mesmerising, A Brief History of Seven Killings is one of the most remarkable and extraordinary novels of the twenty-first century.
    </synopsis>
    <occurrences>
      <promotions>
         <promotionCode>5</promotionCode>
        <promotionNum>1</promotionNum>
        <promotionNum>5</promotionNum>
        <promotionNum>6</promotionNum>
      </promotions>
    </occurrences>
        <occurrences>
      <promotions>
         <promotionCode>5</promotionCode>
        <promotionNum>1</promotionNum>
        <promotionNum>5</promotionNum>
        <promotionNum>6</promotionNum>
      </promotions>
    </occurrences>
  </book>
  <book>
    <title>Leading</title>
    <author>Sir Alex Ferguson</author>
    <year>2015</year>
    <price>7.99</price>
    <publisher>Hodder and Stoughton</publisher>
    <synopsis>
         In this revelatory new book, Sir Alex Ferguson dissects his 38 record-breaking years of management - first in Scotland and then, of course, at Manchester United - to reveal the key tools he used to deliver sustained success on and off the field. From tactics to teamwork, from hiring to firing, from dealing with the boardroom to responding to failure, LEADING investigates the pivotal leadership decisions of an astonishing career.
    </synopsis>
    <occurrences>
      <promotions>
         <promotionCode>6</promotionCode>
        <promotionNum>2</promotionNum>
        <promotionNum>3</promotionNum>
        <promotionNum>6</promotionNum>
      </promotions>
    </occurrences>
  </book>
  <book>
    <title>The Girl on the Train</title>
    <author>Paula Hawkins</author>
    <year>2015</year>
    <price>6.99</price>
    <publisher>Doubleday</publisher>
    <synopsis>
         Rachel catches the same commuter train every morning. She knows it will wait at the same signal each time, overlooking a row of back gardens. She’s even started to feel like she knows the people who live in one of the houses. ‘Jess and Jason’, she calls them. Their life – as she sees it – is perfect. If only Rachel could be that happy.

        And then she sees something shocking. It’s only a minute until the train moves on, but it’s enough. 

        Now everything’s changed. Now Rachel has a chance to become a part of the lives she’s only watched from afar.

        Now they’ll see; she’s much more than just the girl on the train…
    </synopsis>
    <occurrences>
      <promotions>
         <promotionCode>7</promotionCode>
        <promotionNum>1</promotionNum>
        <promotionNum>2</promotionNum>
        <promotionNum>3</promotionNum>
        <promotionNum>4</promotionNum>
      </promotions>
    </occurrences>
  </book>

  <promotion>
    <promotionID>1</promotionID>
    <percentageOff>10</percentageOff>
    <promotionalMerchandise>No</promotionalMerchandise>
    <promotionStartDate>2015-10-14T00:00:00</promotionStartDate>
    <promotionEndDate>2015-10-19T00:00:00</promotionEndDate>
    <promotionLocation>1</promotionLocation>
  </promotion>
  <promotion>
    <promotionID>2</promotionID>
    <percentageOff>15</percentageOff>
    <promotionalMerchandise>No</promotionalMerchandise>
    <promotionStartDate>2015-10-11T00:00:00</promotionStartDate>
    <promotionEndDate>2015-10-16T00:00:00</promotionEndDate>
    <promotionLocation>2</promotionLocation>
  </promotion>
  <promotion>
    <promotionID>3</promotionID>
    <percentageOff>30</percentageOff>
    <promotionalMerchandise>Yes</promotionalMerchandise>
    <promotionStartDate>2015-09-02T00:00:00</promotionStartDate>
    <promotionEndDate>2015-09-07T00:00:00</promotionEndDate>
    <promotionLocation>2</promotionLocation>
  </promotion>
  <promotion>
    <promotionID>4</promotionID>
    <percentageOff>5</percentageOff>
    <promotionalMerchandise>Yes</promotionalMerchandise>
    <promotionStartDate>2015-11-22T00:00:00</promotionStartDate>
    <promotionEndDate>2015-11-27T00:00:00</promotionEndDate>
    <promotionLocation>3</promotionLocation>
  </promotion>
  <promotion>
    <promotionID>5</promotionID>
    <percentageOff>50</percentageOff>
    <promotionalMerchandise>No</promotionalMerchandise>
    <promotionStartDate>2015-08-13T00:00:00</promotionStartDate>
    <promotionEndDate>2015-08-18T00:00:00</promotionEndDate>
    <promotionLocation>1</promotionLocation>
  </promotion>
  <promotion>
    <promotionID>6</promotionID>
    <percentageOff>80</percentageOff>
    <promotionalMerchandise>No</promotionalMerchandise>
    <promotionStartDate>2015-07-01T00:00:00</promotionStartDate>
    <promotionEndDate>2015-07-05T00:00:00</promotionEndDate>
    <promotionLocation>1</promotionLocation>
  </promotion>

  <locations>
    <locationID>1</locationID>
    <location>York</location>
  </locations>
    <locations>
      <locationID>2</locationID>
    <location>London</location>
  </locations>
    <locations>
      <locationID>3</locationID>
    <location>Glasgow</location>
  </locations>
</bookstore>
```

**Live Example:**

I have created a live version of this problem which can be viewed @ http://xsltransform.net/94rmq6J

**The Problem:**

*Part One*

For each `<book/occurrences>` attribute held in my XML data, I'm using my first `<xsl:key>` to cross-reference every available `<book/occurrences/promotionNum>` value (number) against any corresponding `<bookstore/promotion/promotionID>` value.

*Part Two*

If a `<bookstore/promotion/promotionID>` match is found, then the second `<xsl:key>` is triggered targeting `<bookstore/promotion/promotionLocation>` as the search criteria and this attempts to finally match any `<bookstore/locations/locationID>` value.

*Part Three*

If a second and final match is made then the value of `<bookstore/locations/location>` is outputted providing the name of a city in the UK.

Unfortunately I'm struggling to find a way to output unique `<bookstore/locations/location>` values, with cities often repeating two or three time per `<book/occurrences>`.

*Actual Output:*

```
<book>
   <p>
      <strong>Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone</strong>
   </p>
   <p>York</p>
   <p>London</p>
   <p>London</p>
   <p>Glasgow</p>
   <p>York</p>
   <br/>
   <br/>
</book>
<book>
   <p>
      <strong>The Girl with the Dragon Tattoo</strong>
   </p>
   <p>London</p>
   <p>London</p>
   <p>York</p>
   <p>York</p>
   <br/>
   <br/>
</book>
<book>
   <p>
      <strong>Grandpa's Great Escape</strong>
   </p>
   <p>York</p>
   <p>London</p>
   <p>Glasgow</p>
   <br/>
   <br/>
</book>
<book>
   <p>
      <strong>A Brief History of Seven Killings</strong>
   </p>
   <p>York</p>
   <p>York</p>
   <p>York</p>
   <br/>
   <br/>
</book>
<book>
   <p>
      <strong>Leading</strong>
   </p>
   <p>London</p>
   <p>London</p>
   <p>York</p>
   <br/>
   <br/>
</book>
<book>
   <p>
      <strong>The Girl on the Train</strong>
   </p>
   <p>York</p>
   <p>London</p>
   <p>London</p>
   <p>Glasgow</p>
   <br/>
   <br/>
</book>
```

*Desired Output:*

```
<book>
   <p>
      <strong>Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone</strong>
   </p>
   <p>York</p>
   <p>London</p>
   <p>Glasgow</p>
   <br/>
   <br/>
</book>
<book>
   <p>
      <strong>The Girl with the Dragon Tattoo</strong>
   </p>
   <p>London</p>
   <p>York</p>
   <br/>
   <br/>
</book>
<book>
   <p>
      <strong>Grandpa's Great Escape</strong>
   </p>
   <p>York</p>
   <p>London</p>
   <p>Glasgow</p>
   <br/>
   <br/>
</book>
<book>
   <p>
      <strong>A Brief History of Seven Killings</strong>
   </p>
   <p>York</p>
   <br/>
   <br/>
</book>
<book>
   <p>
      <strong>Leading</strong>
   </p>
   <p>London</p>
   <p>York</p>
   <br/>
   <br/>
</book>
<book>
   <p>
      <strong>The Girl on the Train</strong>
   </p>
   <p>York</p>
   <p>London</p>
   <p>Glasgow</p>
   <br/>
   <br/>
</book>
```

So what can I do to fix this problem? Does it relate to `preceding-sibling` or `preceding` in my `<xsl:key>` or would a [Muenchian Method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) approach work, using some form of a `generate-id` on `<book/occurrences/promotionNum>`? I'm sure it is one of those three solutions but I'm not sure which?

Any help would be greatly appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you simply want

```
      <xsl:for-each select="key('location-by-id', key('prom-by-id', occurrences/promotions/promotionNum)/promotionLocation)">

          <p><xsl:value-of select="location"/></p>



      </xsl:for-each>
```